# Retrieve application state from background thread?

Tags: ios, uikit, uiapplication

I'd like to get `UIApplication.shared.applicationState` from a background thread. If I try to get the application state from a background thread, I get errors when accessing it since it's not the main thread (since it's a `UIKit` API).

The reason I'm doing this is so I can log events that also includes information such as the current application state. Logging events for me is happening in the background so it does not lock up the main thread.

Is there an alternative for getting the application state within a background thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup notifications for changes to the state on the main thread and assign them atomically to a variable. That variable can now be accessed atomically as well from your background thread.